# How to simulate a steady-state utilization distribution in the R package amt

Tags: r, prediction

I am trying to simulate a steady-state utilization distribution from a step-selection function in the R package [`amt`](https://github.com/jmsigner/amt) by reproducing the code described in [Signer et al. 2019](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ece3.4823), but the functions `habitat_kernel()`, `movement_kernel()`, and `simulate_ud()` are not in the current version of `amt` (0.2.1.0). Aside from pulling the functions from previous package versions, is there another way to simulate the utilization distribution? My ultimate goal is to generate a prediction map from the step-selection function that considers both the movement and habitat kernels.

Here is a small reproducible example ([data from amt](https://github.com/jmsigner/amt/tree/master/data)) showing what I'd like to do and how we get held up at the `habitat_kernel()`, `movement_kernel()`, and `simulate_ud()` steps:

```
library(amt)

# grab animal movement data
data("deer")

# grab environmental covariate data
data("sh_forest")

# prepare data 
data_ssf <- deer |>
  steps_by_burst() |>
  random_steps(n_control = 15) |>
  extract_covariates(sh_forest) |>
  mutate(forest = factor(forest, levels = 1:0, labels = c("forest", "non-forest")), 
         cos_ta = cos(ta_), 
         log_sl = log(sl_))

# fit model
m1 <- data_ssf |> 
  fit_ssf(case_ ~ forest*cos_ta + forest*log_sl + strata(step_id_))

# grab shape and scale
shape <- sl_distr(m1)$params$shape     # note the 2019 paper has this as: shape <- sl_shape(m1)
scale <- sl_distr(m1)$params$scale     # note the 2019 paper has this as: scale <- sl_scale(m1)

# create a habitat kernel
hk <- habitat_kernel(coef = list(forest = coef(m1["forest"]), resources = sh_forest))

# create a movement kernel
mk <- movement_kernel(scale = scale, shape = shape, template = sh_forest)

# simulate the steady-state UD
ssud <- simulate_ud(movement_kernel = mk,
                    habitat_kernel = hk,
                    start = as.numeric(data_ssf[1, c("x1_", "y1_")]), n = 1e7)
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

note: cross-posted on [amt issues](https://github.com/jmsigner/amt/issues/93)

Comment: If you're going to cross-post to the [amt issues list](https://github.com/jmsigner/amt/issues/93) it would be a good idea to provide reciprocal links (i.e., provide Stack Overflow people with the link to the issues list and vice versa) ... offhand I can't think of a better way to do this than digging out the old version of the package ... I can't immediately see anything in the NEWS file, or in the commit log, that explains why these functions would have gone away ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip (both posts edited) and for having a look